# Check box and label connection

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I am generating a various number of ceckboxes 1-x and labels 1-x:

```
WithEvents lb_cislozakazky As Windows.Forms.Label
WithEvents check_m As Windows.Forms.CheckBox

For i = 1 To x
        check_m = New Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        check_m.Name = "check_manual" & i
        check_m.Top = i * 20 - 19
        check_m.Left = 35
        check_m.Width = 20
        check_m.Height = 20
        Panel2.Controls.Add(check_m)   
 next
```

Now I would like to connect one check box with one label. For exemple: when you check `chckbox1`, `label1` will change color to red.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions to make sure they fir your post before you add the tags! Thank you. I asume this is VB.net, so I tag it with that. Please change to another tag if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an [event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx) for the [CheckStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event to your checkbox before adding it to the panel.  Then in the event handler, just act on the i value in the name to change the properties of the label with the corresponding i value.

```
WithEvents lb_cislozakazky As Windows.Forms.Label
WithEvents check_m As Windows.Forms.CheckBox

For i = 1 To 10
    check_m = New Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    check_m.Name = "check_manual" & i
    check_m.Top = i * 20 - 19
    check_m.Left = 35
    check_m.Width = 20
    check_m.Height = 20
    lb_cislozkzky = New Windows.Forms.Label
    select case (i)
        case 1 : lb_cislozakazky.Caption = "My caption for label 1"
        case 2 : lb_cislozakazky.Caption = "My caption for label 2"
        ...
    end select
    'do sizing positioning of label here:
    lb_cislozakazky.Name = "lb_cislozakazky" & i
    AddHandler lb_cislozakazky.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckStateChanged
    Panel2.Controls.Add(lb_cislozakazky)
    Panel2.Controls.Add(check_m)   
next


Private Sub CheckBox_CheckStateChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
Dim index as integer
Dim msg as string

    if not integer.tryparse(((CheckBox)sender.Name.Remove(0, 15)), index) then index = -1

    if index <> -1 Then
        msg = "You pressed button " & index &", which is next to lb_cislozakazky_" & index & " and the label caption is: " & yourArrayOfLabelCaptions(index)

    Else
        msg = "Error - unable to determine index, check the name: " & (CheckBox)sender.Name & vbcrlf & " and try again!"    
    End If
    MessageBox.Show(msg)
end Sub
```

As you can see I used your existing pseudocode to implement all this.  You didn't specify the array name, so you'll need to replace yourArrayOfLabelCaptions with your array.

Comment: I tried to go by this way, but it wasnt working. I am not able to recognize which one is checked. Could you pleas give me some link to article where could i read about it? I dont know where should i be looking for it. Or if you heva time to make some example i would be realy glad.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) is your [friend](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=CheckBox&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=2)!

Comment: Totaly love this comments! Use google, use brain atc... I have checked what I could.

Comment: I said no such thing, but since you didn't provide even close to functional code and detail a specific issue with the code, I stuck to the resources you'd need to do what you want.  If you check the 'friend' link in my first comment on this answer, you'll see a search of MSDN for the CheckBox control.  The first result has all the details you need to check the .Checked state of the checkbox.  The only thing you might not find there is how to cast the sender object of the event handler to a ChecBox, which I'll gladly answer if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I am able to show msgbox with numbers 1-x when I press button 1-x. That is not problem. But. How can i show MSGbox where is written: "You just press btn_2, which is next to the label _2 and ther is sentence which is writtne in the label:"xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx" The sentence is various....(red from array)

Comment: And that is the thing. I don't know how to make array of control I tried to use this article   [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(v=vs.71).aspx] and some other, but nothig. 

Could you pleas use this